# Populated Droplist Dropdown with Filtering and Autocomplete with DNN (Possible without Host?)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, dotnetnuke

Working within DNN 8.2 I should mention that I do not have Host access. I do not know if that will hinder this process. I am new to DNN so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I am working on a form that will pull from an external db and prepopulate a list of employees.

Since this list will be quite extensive I need to have a filter/autocomplete functionality to help the user find the correct name.

I found a great tool here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx?skin=Windows7

However it's not an option to buy a solution.

I am looking for code similar functionality that I could make work for my purposes if it is possible without Host access.

Comment: This is not a great question for StackOverflow, questions here should be technical in nature not looking for "resources"

Comment: I apologize as I am new to DNN and do not have Host access and was hoping to speak with someone who'd had more extensive DNN experience than I have. I've created forms in purely Java environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer here is that the link you provided will not work, given your access level. If you were to develop a custom extension for this purpose you will need host access to install the module within DNN. Therefore not possible.

Another option might be to see if your installation has a form module already configured. Such as Action Forms or Dynamic Forms.